# How to display Japanese characters from Google Cloud Storage correctly using Java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, encoding, google-cloud-storage

Problem Statement:

I have a file containing Japanese characters located in my Google Cloud Storage Bucket. While downloading and printing the contents of the same, I find that the Japanese characters turn into ???.

I am specifying UTF-8 as the charset in the code. Please help.

Code:

```java
Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of(blobPath, fileName));
LOGGER.info("Blob received with name {}" ,blob.getName());
return new String(blob.getContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to give instructions on how someone can reproduce this.  Without seeing the data source, it's not possible to know if perhaps the data is not what you expect.

Comment: Read the definitive guide at https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Comment: Various components neet to be set for utf8; you probably have something set for latin1 (or some other encoding).

Comment: @DougStevenson The file in GCS has lines separated by "\n". Each line may or may not contain some Japanese characters.

Comment: Right, but we can't see what you're *actually* using here.

Comment: Here is a sample line:

映像 4988111254432 KKIT-4433 Fukushima 50 DVD通常版 佐藤浩市 20201106 3800 2926 23

Comment: @RickJames Can you please send some pointers regarding what to be set?

Comment: This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698794/japanese-character-encoding-in-java) appears to be similar to your question. Remove the encoding method and check the output in terms of its Unicode. I am guessing that the Japanese characters are not encoded correctly in the raw text.

Comment: In Python you can declare the [encoding on the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source) file like this. And Java you do the same when you compile it '-encoding'.